# Distinct by a single field (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I have to following query, which works ok and brings me the results as I wish:

```
SELECT * FROM dv.event 
WHERE status like 'online' OR ATTEMPTS < 5 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID 
ORDER BY by CREATION_DATE ASC LIMIT 5;
```

So, if I have 4 entries, and 1,4 has the same `CUSTOMER_ID`, I get eventually 3 entries as a result, without the 4th entry.
Which is OK, but i'm not sure it's the RIGHT way to do it.
Besides, it's not working as expected using Hibernate:

```
 expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns: EVENT0_.ID
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `like` in `status like 'online'` is useless, it's the same as `status = 'online'`

Comment: Well, SQL answer for the sake of 'is this the right way to achieve the distinction by CUSTOMER_ID'.
The HQL just as a 'plus'

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: You should not use group by without aggregation function  .. . you should use  explicit columns name and distinct

Answer (score 1):

Well, * is not compatible with quality code. Since you are doing grouping, it is best to explicitly tell which columns should be selected. When you have grouping, the selected column should be the one you're grouping on and aggregating functions (such as SUM() or COUNT()) that operate on other columns.

The error states just that - there are columns, which you are selecting and you are not grouping by. For example, you have this table.

```
CustomerID   EventID   Date
20           10        2018-02-02
20           30        2018-03-03
```

So, if you group by CustomerID, you have various event data for CustomerID 20. This data would be lost, since grouping makes 1 row per set. You can select the first event as:

```
Select t1.CustomerID,
MIN(t1.Date) as First_Event_Date <--MIN is aggregating function.
From MyTable t1

GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Then, if you want the event ID, you should join back the table on CustomerID and First_Event_Date.

If you just use *, at best you get an error, at worst you implicitly lose data, which you may know or may not know about.